# Mock a static/external method in a function-under-test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

What's the preferred) way to mock a (static) method that's used in a nested call?

So in this example, `A::foo` is to be unit-tested and any external calls i.e, `B::get()` would need to be mocked so there's no dependency on whether `B::get()` functionally works or not just to test `A::foo()`.

```
class B
{
    public:
    static int get()
    {
        return 10;
    }
};

class A
{
    public:
    void foo()    // test foo()
    {
        auto val = B::get();  // mock this call
        // stuff
    }
};
```

There's one way I came up with via dependency injection however that requires making changes to the production code just for the sake of testing. Are there approaches that require least amount of changes in `class A` and `class B`/production code or nothing at all to allow mocking `B::get()`?

```
class BInterface
{
    public:
    virtual int get() = 0;
};

class B
{
    public:
    static int get()
    {
        cout << "10\n";
        return 10;
    }
};

class A
{
    BInterface* ptr;

    public:
    void set(BInterface* p)
    {
        ptr = p;
    }
    
    void foo() 
    {
        if (ptr) 
        {
            ptr->get();
            return;
        }
        // default logic
    }
};

class BMock : public BInterface
{
    MOCK_METHOD(int, get, (), override);
};

int main()
{
    BMock bmock;
    A a;
    a.set(&bmock);
    a.foo();
}
```

Would it make sense to have something like the following?

```
class AMock 
{
  public:
  void foo()
  {
     BMock bMock; 
     bMock.get();
  }
};

// stub for A
void A::foo()
{
   AMock aMock;
   aMock.foo();
   // copy paste the production code (??)
}
```

Comment: If `B::get` and `A::foo` are implemented in separate translation units and not inline, you may be able to simply link use the linker an alternative implementation. The drawback is that you may need to produce multiple test executables to repeat this kind of testing for different classes. Another alternative would be to make `A` a template class (or an alias for one) receiving `B` as template parameter...

Comment: Change `void foo()` to `void foo(int)`, and call it with `a.foo(B::get());` in the production code, and `a.foo(mock_value);` in the test code.  Having the function body *call* the getter is a **hidden dependency**.  Change hidden dependencies into passed-in parameters.